# Configuring eclipse CDT and openCV

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv, windows-7

I am trying to configure OpenCV and eclipse CDT (Juno) in Windows 7. I have already installed MinGW and have been using eclipse with MinGW to write C++ programs. I am now trying to incorporate the OpenCV libraries. Below are the steps I have followed:

1. Download and extract OpenCV 2.4.2 to F:\Applications\opencv
2. Create new eclipse C++ project
3. under project properties under c/c++ build > settings > GCC C++ Compiler > Includes >  Include Paths (-I) I have added *"F:\Applications\opencv\build\include\"*
4. under MinGW C++ Linnker > Libraries > Libraries (-l) I have added "opencv_core242", "opencv_imgproc242", "opencv_highgui242"
5. under MinGW C++ Linker > Libraries > Library search path (-L) I have added *"F:\Applications\opencv\build\x86\lib"*

I have then tried to write the simple program:

```
#include "opencv2\opencv.hpp"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
int main(void)
{
    Mat A;
    A = imread("lena.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

    imshow("image", A);

    cout << "Done" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

However nothing happens and I don't even get the "Done" message in the output. I am stumped now as I'm new to C++ and OpenCV and am not quite sure how to debug this and move forward.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: I have same configuration (besides that I am using 2.4.5), and there is no opencv\build\x86\lib ("F:\Applications\opencv\build\x86\lib") on my system but only opencv\build\x86\mingw\bin? Where did you get that path? I have the same problem as you.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, I had to add F:\Applications\opencv\build\x86\mingw\bin; to my system path

Comment: Have you added that path to the SYSTEM VARAIBLES PATH or you added it to the 5. under MinGW C++ Linker > Libraries > Library search path (-L) ? If so, have you removed "F:\Applications\opencv\build\x86\lib" because I don't think that path exist?