# OpenCV Function Argument Error

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv

I'm using OpenCV template matching, am getting several errors and don't know what the root cause is. I'm using Eclipse Juno.

Sample line with the error:

```
cv::Mat ref = cv::imread("picture.png");
```

Error:

```
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
? imread(const ? &, int)
'
```

Based on the error, I thought to add an integer to the arguments, but that didn't solve the issue. I also tried making the string on a separate line and pulling the address from that, but that didn't help either.

I'm also getting another error:

```
C:\Users\User\opencv\build\include/opencv/cv.hpp:50:16: fatal error: 
cv.h: No such file or directory
#include <cv.h>
            ^
```

compilation terminated.

which could be the real issue. I don't understand why this error is being thrown though since that library is included in the project. I even tried including `cv.h` and `cv.hpp` on their own (not as a part of the whole library) but that just causes dozens of `undefined reference` errors.

Whole Code:

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv/cv.hpp>
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  cv::Mat ref = cv::imread("picture.png");
  cv::Mat tpl = cv::imread("template.png");
  if (ref.empty() || tpl.empty())
    return -1;

  cv::Mat gref, gtpl;
  cv::cvtColor(ref, gref, CV_BGR2GRAY);
  cv::cvtColor(tpl, gtpl, CV_BGR2GRAY);

  cv::Mat res(ref.rows-tpl.rows+1, ref.cols-tpl.cols+1, CV_32FC1);
  cv::matchTemplate(gref, gtpl, res, CV_TM_CCOEFF_NORMED);
  cv::threshold(res, res, 0.8, 1., CV_THRESH_TOZERO);

  while (true)
  {
    double minval, maxval, threshold = 0.8;
    cv::Point minloc, maxloc;
    cv::minMaxLoc(res, &minval, &maxval, &minloc, &maxloc);

    if (maxval >= threshold)
    {
        cv::rectangle(
            ref,
            maxloc,
            cv::Point(maxloc.x + tpl.cols, maxloc.y + tpl.rows),
            CV_RGB(0,255,0), 2
        );
        cv::floodFill(res, maxloc, cv::Scalar(0), 0, cv::Scalar(.1), cv::Scalar(1.));
    }
    else
        break;
  }

  cv::imshow("reference", ref);
  cv::waitKey();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have been able to run opencv calls before in you program right? Like you have compiled and ran before - so its not a linking error?

Comment: According to this link: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html
The call should be `cv::imread("your_file_name", 1);`  So please change your code to what is documented, and then report back.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I did and it did not help. That was one of the first things I tried.

Comment: @Jay It very well may be a linking error. Check out the update I posted.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The 1 at the end doesn't matter. It defaults to 1. That is just for coloring. 0 is grey scale.

Comment: It is defiantly a linking error. The program can't read cv.h. Lets see your make file. And if eclipse is doing it for you. You should google `linking opencv with eclipse` or something of that nature.

Comment: @Jay I've tried the steps that multiple guides suggest (most agree on pretty much what to do [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12621155/configuring-eclipse-cdt-and-opencv] for example). Still no luck, as for the make file, I don't have one (that's made by me at least.) Interestingly, no tutorial mentions one, even when setting up OpenCV for the first time.

Comment: What system you on. Mac/Windows/Linux?

Comment: @Jay Windows 7, OpenCV version 2.4.9

Comment: ewww. Well, Do you have mingw?

Comment: haha yes, that's what I've got